# Is there a way to check all loaded namepace?

Tags: r, namespaces

I think in R I can see all attached packages, either using `search()` or in Rstudio clicking the arrow besides global environment.

However it seems I can't see which package is in current name space.

I mean I physically uninstalled some package, but I could still use the method inside it.

But after I `unloadNamespace()` that package, I can't call that function.

That is the reason I want to see the list of current active namespace.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but perhaps, try `sessionInfo()`

Answer (score 2):

In a fresh session, let's load a package first.

```
> library(MASS)
```

You can find the information typing `sessionInfo()`.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
[1] C

time zone: Europe/Zurich
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] MASS_7.3-60.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.2 tools_4.3.2
```

Basically `sessionInfo()` is a nested `"list"`,

```
> class(unclass(sessionInfo()))
[1] "list"
```

which has `names`;

```
> names(sessionInfo())
 [1] "R.version"   "platform"    "locale"      "tzone"       "tzcode_type"
 [6] "running"     "RNGkind"     "basePkgs"    "otherPkgs"   "loadedOnly" 
[11] "matprod"     "BLAS"        "LAPACK"      "LA_version"
```

if you want access sub elements like the `"loadedOnly"`, you can do

```
> sessionInfo()$loadedOnly |> names()
[1] "compiler"   "tools"      "rstudioapi"
```

maybe with its version.

```
> sessionInfo()$loadedOnly |> sapply(`[[`, "Version")
  compiler      tools rstudioapi 
   "4.3.2"    "4.3.2"   "0.15.0"
```

The same way you can do this with the other names, e.g.

```
> sessionInfo()$otherPkgs |> sapply(`[[`, "Version")
        MASS 
"7.3-60.0.1"
```

### Example

Using a function with double colon only loads the namespace, i.e. doesn't attach the package. Let's do this with `tictoc::tic`. Then we `remove` it but see it's still loaded in the namespace and functions can be accessed. The described method above shows what's loaded and probably needs care of `unloadNamespace`.

```
> tictoc::tic()
> remove.packages('tictoc')
Removing package from '/home/jay/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
> library(tictoc)
Error in library(tictoc) : there is no package called 'tictoc'
> tictoc::toc()
2.971 sec elapsed
> sessionInfo()$loadedOnly |> names()
[1] "compiler" "tictoc"   "tools"   
Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  DESCRIPTION file of package 'tictoc' is missing or broken
> unloadNamespace('tictoc')
> sessionInfo()$loadedOnly |> names()
[1] "compiler" "tools"   
> tictoc::tic()
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called 'tictoc'
> install.packages('tictoc')
```

Comment: Using the list result of `sessionInfo` there are three places you can find package names that should be on a search path for some or all environments: "basePkgs"  , "otherPkgs"      
 and  "loadedOnly"

Comment: Hi, the answer has the correct way, Thanks, you has everything I needed, Because I loaded it with library so I can only find it in otherPkgs, the only packages in loadedOnly is the one whos is not attached but loaded

Comment: @IRTFM Yes of course, thanks. This reminded me of a similar problem I had when I installed a new version of a personal package during an interactive session without using `unloadNamespace` first. Even though I updated a function, it still had the same bug.

Comment: @cloudscomputes I added an example that I thought might apply to your issue, but we're probably talking past each other.

Comment: sure,there is one interesting topic related to this, when you work in r project in rstudio for a while, you notice there are some pkgs loaded not attched, and even you restart the r session, they are still there, while a brand new session didn't have so many  pkgs loaded, but which pkgs are kept even after restart r session is not quite clear for me, I used tictoc::tic() and save it in an R file but it is not preserved in the loaded name space, if you have time, you can help me on this, or I can post a new question and @ you if you want.

Comment: @cloudscomputes I am sure that your previous workspace always gets reloaded. Deactivate in RStudio: Tools > General > uncheck all "R Sessions" and "Workspace" select "Save .RData on exit: never, the rest you can leave checked.